# How do I select unique elements from a Promise<Array[]> in Angular 2/4?

Tags: javascript, angular

Little context, I have an API that returns a competition with a link to its matches and each match has a link to the teams that played.

My intention for now, is to build a standings table based on the competition matches therefore, my first step is to print a list of unique "teams" from that array of matches. That is I need to go through all the matches, check the home and away teams, and if the team is not present, push it into the list.

Here is the tricky part, I have the teams like this:

```
match.away = this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.awayTeam.href);
match.home = this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.homeTeam.href);
```

And my getTeam() method is returning a promise **Team**.

```
getTeam(id: string): Promise<Team> {
    return this.http.get(id)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json() as Team)
           .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

The **Team** class has **teamName: string;** which is the value I need to verify to build the array and that is the part I need help with. I have an OnInit implemented that goes like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.teams = [];
      this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.competitionService.getCompetition(+params['id']))
    .subscribe(competition => {
      this.competitionService.getMatches(competition)
        .then(
          matches => {
            matches.forEach(match => {
              match.away = this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.awayTeam.href);
              match.home = this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.homeTeam.href);
              match.away.then(away => {
                var found = this.teams.find(team => {
                  return team.teamName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(away.teamName)
                });
                if(!found) {
                  this.teams.push(away);
                }
              });
              match.home.then(home => {
                var found = this.teams.find(team => {
                  return team.teamName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(home.teamName)
                });
                if(!found) {
                  this.teams.push(home);
                }
              });
            });
            return matches;
          }
        ).then(matches => 
          this.matches = matches
        );
      this.competition = competition
  });
}
```

What I tried to do there is resolve the Promise first and check for the teams' presence in my array and if it is !found then push it to the list.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let team of teams">
        <button md-raised-button>{{team.teamName}}</button>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

But the result is a list of each team in each match, so appearantly the **push** part is working because the array **teams: Team[];** is being populated and printed correctly, but the verification is not.

Please don't kill me for my code cause I have 0 idea on this, I'm just learning on the fly, ot only Angular but to code.

**So my Question Is:**

How do I build an array of unique teams from that promise of matches?

Furthermore, how do you usually split arrays for these calculations? Every research I found points me to a **"Custom Pipe"** but it seems to be filtering the view only, After I have my array of teams, I have to make calculations on each of the matches for Goals, points, etc, so it does not seem that it will work for me.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a new method to delegate the `teams` array population:

```
addToSet(team): void {
    let teamNames: string[] = this.teams.map((team) => team.teamName.toLocaleLowerCase());

    if (teamNames.lastIndexOf(team.teamName.toLocaleLowerCase()) === -1) {
       this.teams.push(team);
    }
}
```

And then, substitute this part

```
var found = this.teams.find(team => {
    return team.teamName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(home.teamName)
});
if(!found) {
    this.teams.push(home);
}
```

for

```
this.addToSet(home);
```

Also, to be sure that both promises are fulfilled before going on with the array loading, you could wrap both `getTeam` calls with `Promise.all`.

```
Promise.all([
   this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.awayTeam.href),
   this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.homeTeam.href)
]).then((teams) => {
   match.away = teams[0];
   match.home = teams[1];
});
```

EDIT: putting it all together

```
addToSet(team): void {
    let teamNames: string[] = this.teams.map((team) => team.teamName.toLocaleLowerCase());

    if (teamNames.lastIndexOf(team.teamName.toLocaleLowerCase()) === -1) {
       this.teams.push(team);
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
     // rest of the initialization
     matches.forEach(match => {
         Promise.all([
             this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.awayTeam.href),
             this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.homeTeam.href)
         ]).then(teams => {
             match.away = teams[0];
             match.home = teams[1];

             this.addToSet(away);
             this.addToSet(home);
         });
     });
 }
```

EDIT 2: added `toLocaleLowerCase()` in `addToSet()` for check. I'm assuming the `getTeam` returns a single object, otherwise, you'll need to enforce the returned object schema.

Comment: I tried the solution, although I can build my array of teams, I can't build it with Unique values, is just listing every team